# how does component rendering mechanism work in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In React, a component re-renders when its props/state is changed.

how does redux know(compute) which specific component(DOM) to render/re-rendering whenever an action is dispatched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux), the `connect` higher order component subscribes to changes in the store, then passes the store's state into a mapStateToProps function that you write, and then the result is passed into your component as props. From there, the change in props leads to the standard react lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

In React a component get re-rendered when props/state is updated. So firing action will not update any component unless you are passing redux state to component as a prop.

action -> reducer( update some state in reducer) -> now state is updated -> component checks if prop(from redux) is updated -> yes -> re-render component.